# Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS: svn & gnome-keyring doesn't work headless

Tags: command-line, 20.04, svn, gnome-keyring

I'm woking on a AWS EC2 server running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
Using svn and it's prompting password for every single svn command. It's annoying and tiring.

Tried to use gnome-keyring, and it's a whole new pandora's box. Looks like most people are wrangling lions to get it to play nice.

I just want a solution on a headless or command line environment which svn doesn't prompt me every time.

Thanks.
/waisun

Comment: I'm confused why you are running a headless desktop.